# ResourceBundle.getBundle and Websphere

Tags: java, websphere

I have some code like this:

```
 resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
      "com.something.whatever.txt", getLocale());
```

This code is part of an app which is run by websphere.

`com.something.whatever.properties` is a text file which is then jarred and deployed.

The question is:
Can I easily override it ?
somehow redeploy just this file rather than the whole app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can But I strongly suggest you restart the application before trying.

Comment: Thanks. can you tell me more ?

Comment: You can simply copy the file to a classpath directory that precedes that jar that contains the resource file. I usually avoid jarring resource files.